# Scrum compatibility with PMBOK® Guide

Tags: scrum, methodology, project-management-style, pmi-framework

My question is quite simple : Is Scrum methodology compatible with PMBOK® Guide ? In other words How can we manage a project using the Scrum methodology in the PMI Framework?

Comment: You should take a look at the Chaos Report from the Standish group in Boston. They analysed over 70k software projects and found an inverse relationship between delivering value to your customers and managing with PMI/Prince2 methods. It's that simple...

Comment: This question is far to vague. Scrum itself is a framework, within Agile. What aspect of the PMI framework are you trying to wrap around scrum, and why?

Comment: [Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/) is a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMI is fully compatible with Scrum - they even have a [PMI Agile Certified Practitioner (PMI-ACP)®](https://www.pmi.org/certifications/types/agile-acp) certification - to quote from that page:

> If you’re experienced using agile approaches, have good collaboration skills, eagerly embrace complexity and thrive on rapid response times, then your talents are in demand.
>
> The PMI Agile Certified Practitioner (PMI-ACP)® formally recognizes your knowledge of agile principles and your skill with agile techniques. It will make you shine even brighter to your employers, stakeholders and peers.
>
> The PMI-ACP® is our fastest growing certification, and it’s no wonder. Organizations that are highly agile and responsive to market dynamics complete more of their projects successfully than their slower-moving counterparts — 75 percent versus 56 percent — as shown in our 2015 Pulse of the Profession® report.
>
> The PMI-ACP spans many approaches to agile such as **Scrum**, Kanban, Lean, extreme programming (XP) and test-driven development (TDD.) So it will increase your versatility, wherever your projects may take you.

Comment: I accept this answer. But I meant scrum compatibility with PMBOCK guide.

Comment: [PMI definition of a project](https://www.pmi.org/about/learn-about-pmi/what-is-project-management) raises concerns regarding their *Agile(tm)* certification.

Answer (score 8):

I think questions like this need to be answered with great care. PMBoK is not necessarily incompatible with Scrum but it has to be said that PMBoK  started out very much as a predictive planning approach to projects. You could argue that "initiate, plan, control etc." is being applied to each sprint but that was not how PMBoK evolved.  The fact that PMI have a certification aimed at Agile is not proof of compatibility it is about revenue.

Agile, most of all, is about flexibility.  The mindset between the two can be worlds apart.

Answer (score -3):

PMBOK tells you how to manage projects in general and PMI-ACP tells you how to manage Agile projects and teaches you about Agile methodologies which are not used in constructions for example.

It is like comparing fruit to apple; in other words, Agile is specific and PMBOK is generic. But both lead you to the same thing.

PMBOK encourages you if you have a changeable culture then device your project into phases and make the phases as small as possible.

Comment: The [agile software development philosophy](http://agilemanifesto.org/) is not specific; there is no **A**gile. Different frameworks and methods, i.e. Scrum and XP, have specifics.

Comment: What I ment to say is that it is specific to some sort of projects  (software), but PMP was created to cover all types of projects (software, construction, event management and so many types).

Comment: Agile and PMBoK ask very different questions. The instructor that ran the PMI course that I was in, explained that it started off as a way of managing heavyweight projects like constructing nuclear submarines. Despite its efforts to re-invent itself it still carries a lot of that baggage around.